# Database combobox fill input box with value then open the URL in new browser window

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, combobox

I've been searching around and I've watched several videos but I haven't been able to get the result I'm looking for.

1. I'm trying to have a combobox populated with **webname** via a database using php.  In the database I have 3 fields: **webid**, **webname**, and **weburl**.
2. When I select an item from the dropdown I want an input box to display the URL of the corresponding **webname**.
3. Have a button than once click will open the displayed URL in a seperate browser window.

I have to combo box populating correct but I cant get the proper URL to display when I change the dropdown.

**my Index.php**

```
<body id="top">

<?php
    $cn=mysql_connect("dbHost","dbUser","dbPW") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("dbName",$cn) or die(mysql_error());
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblName ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<select id="loads" name="Loads" size=1 style="position:absolute;left:133px;top:10px;width:81px;height:22px;z-index:1;">

<?php
    while($ri = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<option value=" .$ri['webname'] . ">" . $ri['webname'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select> "  
?>
 <input type="text" id="ShipperName" name="ShipperName" value="">

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
 <script>

  $(document).ready(function(){ /* PREPARE THE SCRIPT */

    $("#loads").change(function(){ /* TRIGGER THIS WHEN USER HAS SELECTED DATA FROM THE SELECT FIELD */

      var WebName = $(this).val(); /* STORE THE SELECTED LOAD NUMBER TO THIS VARIABLE */

      $.ajax({ /* START AJAX */

        type: "POST", /* METHOD TO USE TO PASS THE DATA */
        url: "action.php", /* THE FILE WHERE WE WILL PASS THE DATA */
        data: {"WebName": WebName}, /* THE DATA WE WILL PASS TO action.php */
        dataType: 'json', /* DATA TYPE THAT WILL BE RETURNED FROM action.php */
        success: function(result){

          $("#ShipperName").val(result.shippername);
        /*  $("#ShipperAddr").val(result.shipperaddr); */
        }

      }); /* END OF AJAX */   

    }); /* END OF CHANGE #loads */

  });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**my action.php**

```
<?php

  if(!empty($_POST["WebName"])){

    /* RE-ESTABLISH YOUR CONNECTION */
    $con = new mysqli("dbHost","dbUser","dbPW","dbTable");

    /* CHECK CONNECTION */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
      exit();
    }

    /* PREPARE YOUR QUERY */
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT weburl, webid FROM tblName WHERE webname = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST["WebName"]); /* PARAMETIZE THIS VARIABLE TO YOUR QUERY */
    $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE QUERY */
    $stmt->bind_result($shippername, $shipperaddress); /* BIND THE RESULTS TO THESE VARIABLES */
    $stmt->fetch(); /* FETCH THE RESULTS */
    $stmt->close(); /* CLOSE THE PREPARED STATEMENT */

    /* RETURN THIS DATA TO THE MAIN FILE */
    echo json_encode(array("shippername" => $shippername, "shipperaddr" => $shipperaddress));

  } /* END OF IF NOT EMPTY loadnumber */

?>
```

Comment: But what is the issue you are getting?

Comment: the textbox is showing the same Url no mater what I select.

Comment: I found a nice article similar to your question here http://phppot.com/jquery/jquery-dependent-dropdown-list-countries-and-states/

Comment: @sForSujit Thanks.  That is a great example as uses foreign keys to link the data.  I'm trying to accomplish this using 1 table.  I will continue to filter through code to see what I can come up with.

Comment: Sure follow that @ftvKing

Comment: So I've figured that my problem is in 1 of 2 places. I'll start with my select statement .  I'm not sure if this is correct as it isn't yielding any results when the function is triggered.   `query ="SELECT * FROM tblName WHERE webname = '" . $_POST["webname"] . "'";`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to fill the text box with URL, But you are assigning ShipperName to the textbox like this :

```
$("#ShipperName").val(result.shippername);
```

This should be :

```
$("#ShipperName").val(result.weburl);
```

Comment: I tried it and that didn't work.  The shippername was passed back from here ` RETURN THIS DATA TO THE MAIN FILE */
    echo json_encode(array("shippername" => $shippername, "shipperaddr" => $shipperaddress));`

Comment: Did you debug your code, and see whether all values are coming in the result?

Comment: Not a console, i mean put a debugger and check if you get the values

Comment: Im writing and testing in DW but I tried to run the debugger in visual studio code without success.  I did a little more troubleshooting and the value I'm getting in the input box appears to be the record in the table.  I deleted some records to confirm it.